# Isomorphisms between $(\mathbb Z_4,+)$ and $(U_5,*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am asked to find all the isomorphisms between $G = (\mathbb Z_4,+)$ and $H = (U_5,*)$.

I solved it as follows: we will have two isomorphism corresponding to the two generators of $U_5$.

The first isomorphism : $\phi([x]_4)$ = $[2]_5^x$

The second isomorphism is: $\phi([x]_4)$ = $[3]_5^x$

Notice that [2] and [3] are the only generators of $U_5$ one can check it systematically or use the fact that $a^m$ is a generator iff gcd(m,4) = 1.

So I just wanted a verification of my work I showed that they are bijective, well defined, and is a homomorphism.

Comment: What is $U_5$? The cardinalities of the two do not seem equal…

Comment: The set of units in Z5, so its {1,2,3,4}.

Comment: Looks OK to me.