# How many possible isomorphisms do we have between G and H?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=(Z_4,+)$ and let $H=(U_5,*)$ where $U_5 = \{[1],[2],[3],[4] \}$ . I know that $[1]$ and $[3]$ are both generators for $G$. I also know that $[2]$ and $[3]$ are both generators for $H$. In order to construct isomorphism we have to map a generator to a generator. And so, $\phi([1]^x_4) = [2]^x_5$ is an isomorphism from $G \longrightarrow H$. Also $\phi([1]^x_4) = [3]^x_5$ is another isomorphism from $G \longrightarrow H$.

Can we do the same thing for the other generator of $G$. And so we would have two more isomorphisms, Namely $\phi([3]^x_4) = [2]^x_5$ and $\phi([3]^x_4) = [3]^x_5$  is that true ? and if it is true, then does that mean that if we have $n$ generators for a group $G$ and $m$ generators of a group $H$ then i would have $nm$ isomorphisms in total ? Thanks

Comment: interesting question !

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1119900/39599).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that: $\phi\left([1]_4^x\right)=[2]_5^x$ is the same map as $\phi\left([3]_4^x\right)=[3]_5^x$.